# Numbering new environment with chapter/section

Tags: floats, numbering, captions

If I have a new environment defined (with, say, `trivfloat`), is it possible to get that section to number with chapter/section? I use `\numberwithin` for equations, figures, and tables.

For example, my equations and figures are numbered 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, ...
(or even 1.1.1, 1.1.2, ...) But if I have a new float type (say, graph), `\numberwithin` won't work.

```
\trivfloat{graph}
\numberwithin{graph}{section} % Error...
```

Same happens if I use `\DeclareCaptionType` from the caption package.

Any thoughts on how to get this effect?

Comment: `\DeclareCaptionType` resp. `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` has an optional parameter `within=section`, so there is no need for `\numberwithin` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `trivfloat` package seems to defer (much of) the definition of its new floats using `\AtBeginDocument`, so you also have to use `\AtBeginDocument{\numberwithin{graph}{section}}` to change the floats' numbering.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{trivfloat}

\trivfloat{graph}

\AtBeginDocument{\numberwithin{graph}{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{graph}[h]
(Graph content)
\caption{A graph}
\end{graph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And cannot you simply put `\numberwithin{graph}{section}` _just after_ `\begin{document}` ?

Comment: Awesome! That works wonderfully. And nice explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: @tohecz I prefer preamble solutions because they may be used in a user's custom `mypackages.sty` or `myclass.cls`.

Comment: @tohecz Yes, I tried that and it works also. However, the AtBeginDocument is better for me as this is going in a .sty file.

Comment: @tohecz: Like with many suggestions there *are* alternatives. In this case, separating content from setup (macro construction and package inclusion) is usually good practice.

Comment: I'm just afraid of soon having to use `\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument{...}}` ...